# Collapse all and in that expand only one item

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I have four content tabs which has expand collapse icon in each tabs, where collapse all and expand all works fine. what i need exactly is:
1. when i expand/collapse all navigate to other tab and come back same tab than it will remember the status of  expand/collapse all.
2. but when i click expand all, after expanding if i click one item as collapse, if i navigate to other tab and i come back than collapsed one item is not remebering, it is expanded status only.
I want to expand all and want to click some items collapse, i want to rembeber both expand all and collapse some of them.

```
   function getStudentHistoryReport(sT){
    $("#aExpand").text("Expand All");//Default all tabs showing Expand All
    $("#ulTabs > li").removeClass("active");
    var sTN = sT.replace(/\s/g, "");
    $("#ulTabs > #" + sTN).addClass("active");
    if(sT == "Class Schedule"){
        $("#aExpand").hide();
        var lC = StarsUtility.GetData("getshclassschedule", {"lSID" : $("#SC_STUDENT_ID").val()}, true);
        var sC = "";
        if(lC.length > 0){
            $("#divNoData").css('display', 'none');
            $.each(lC, function(i1, o1){
                sC += "<tr>";
                sC += "<td class='text-left'>"+ o1.teacherName +"</td>";
                sC += "<td class='text-left'>"+o1.className+" (Per "+ o1.period +", Sect "+o1.section+ ")" +"</td>";
                /*sC += "<td>"+o1.period+"</td>";
            sC += "<td>"+o1.section+"</td>";*/
                /*sC += "<td>A</td>";
            sC += "<td><div class='progressBar' id='max96'></div></td>";*/
                sC += "</tr>";
            });
            $("#tbdClass").html(sC);
            $("#divClassSchedule").show();
        } else {$("#divNoData").html("No Class Schedule data."); $("#divNoData").css('display', '');}
        $("#divTabs").hide();
        $("#divReportTab").hide();
    } else {
        var mp = StarsUtility.GetData("getshreport", {"lSID" : $("#SC_STUDENT_ID").val(), "sTab" : sT}, true); // year as key and value as map
        oSH.studentHistoryReport = mp;
        if(StarsUtility.GetSize(mp) == 0) {$("#divNoData").html("No Assessments data."); $("#divNoData").css('display', ''); $("#aExpand").hide();} //You could use StarsUtility.GetSize()
        else{$("#divNoData").css('display', 'none'); $("#aExpand").show();}
        var sH = "";
        sH += '<ul>';
        var Tl = 0; // Total length of Assessments in all years.
        $.each(mp, function(k, v){
            Tl += StarsUtility.GetSize(v);
        });
        var lT = (sTN in oSH.mpRemove) ? oSH.mpRemove[sTN] : new Array();
        if(Tl != lT.length){
        $.each(mp, function(k, v){
            var yr = k.replace("___", "");
            var mT = v;
            var lH = new Array();
            for(var i1 in mT) {
                var oSH1 = mT[i1];
                lH = Object.keys(oSH1.scoreTopic);
                break;
            }
                sH += '<li><span class="plus-minus" id="spYear_'+yr +'_' + sTN +'" onclick="toggleYearandAssessment(this, 1);"><i id="icon_spYear_' + yr + '_' + sTN +'" class="text-orange icon-minus-sign" name="iYearPlusMinus"></i></span>';
            sH += '<h5>'+yr+'</h5>';
                sH += '<ul id="ulYear_'+yr +'_' + sTN +'" name="ulYear"><li>';
                sH += '<table class="table" style="width: 830px;">';
            sH += '<thead><tr>';
            sH += '<th class="text-left" colspan="2">Assessment Name</th>';
            sH += '<th>Subject</th>';
            sH += '<th>Test Date</th>';
            sH += '<th>Level<br/>Tested</th>';
            for(var h=0; h<lH.length; h++){
                if(lH[h] == "null") continue;
                if(lH[h] == "Raw Score") sH += '<th>Raw<br/>Score</th>';
                else if(lH[h] == "Scale Score") sH += '<th>Scale<br/>Score</th>';
                else sH += '<th>'+lH[h]+'</th>';
            }
            sH += '<th>Hide</th>';
            sH += '</tr></thead><tbody>';
            $.each(mT, function(k1, v1){
                var o1 = v1;
                if(null != o1.assessmentName) { //This is not correct. Just adding this to make local assessment tab working for lawndale fix.
                    var lSO = ((o1.objectives && o1.objectives.length > 0) ? o1.objectives : o1.standards);
                        sH += '<tr id="tr_'+k1.replace("___", "")+'" style='+(jQuery.inArray(parseInt(k1.replace("___", "")), lT) > -1 ? "display:none" : "")+'>';
                    sH += '<td style="width: 20px;">';
                    sH += '<span class="plus-minus toggle-assess-info" id="sp_'+k1.replace("___", "")+'" onclick="toggleYearandAssessment(this, 2);">';
                    if(lSO.length > 0) sH += '<i class='+(jQuery.inArray(("sp_"+k1.replace("___", "")), oSH.lstTIds) > -1 ? ("icon-minus-sign") : "icon-plus-sign")+' name="iPlusMinus"></i>';
                    sH += '</span></td>';
                    sH += '<td class="text-left">'+o1.assessmentName+'</td>';
                    sH += '<td>'+ o1.subjectName +'</td>';
                    sH += '<td>'+ o1.testDate +'</td>';
                    sH += '<td>'+ o1.gradeLevelTest+'</td>';
                    for(var h = 0; h < lH.length; h++){
                        if(lH[h] == "null") continue;
                        var sFN = ( (!StarsUtility.IsEmptyObject(o1.scoreTopic) && (StarsUtility.IsValidObject(o1.scoreTopic[lH[h]]) && o1.scoreTopic[lH[h]].indexOf(".000") > -1 && lH[h] != "Percent Correct")) ? parseInt(o1.scoreTopic[lH[h]]) : o1.scoreTopic[lH[h]]);// Percent Correct, Raw Score we will get .000
                        if(lH[h] == "Performance Level") {
                            sH += '<td><i class='+(sFN != "-" ? "bubble-7" : "")+' style="height: auto; width: auto; ' + (sFN != "-" ? 'border-color:#'+o1.performanceLevelColor+'!important"' : '') +'>' + (sFN) +'</i></td>';
                        } else if(lH[h] == "Percent Correct"){
                            var sA = new Array();
                            if( StarsUtility.IsValidObject( sFN ) && sFN.indexOf("|~|") > -1) sA = sFN.split("|~|");
                            var iPc =  ( (StarsUtility.IsValidObject( sFN ) && sFN.indexOf("|~|")) > -1 ? ((StarsUtility.IsNumber(sA[0]) && sA[0] > -1 && sA[1] > -1) ? ((parseFloat(sA[0])/parseFloat(sA[1])) * 100).toFixed(oSH.decimalCount) + "%" : "-") : sFN);
                            if(iPc != "-") iPc = isNaN(parseFloat(iPc).toFixed(oSH.decimalCount)) ? "-" : parseFloat(iPc).toFixed(oSH.decimalCount);
                            sH+= (iPc == '-' ? '<td>-</td>' : '<td class="col-perc-bar-1"><div class="percent">' +iPc+'%</div><div class="progressBar" id="max'+iPc+'"><div style="width: '+iPc+'%; background:#'+o1.performanceLevelColor+'!important;"></div></div></td>');
                            } else {
                                if(lH[h] == "Raw Score") sFN = StarsUtility.RemoveTrialingZero(sFN.toString());
                                sH += '<td>'+ ((lH[h] == "Raw Score" || lH[h] == "Scale Score") ? (StarsUtility.IsNumber(sFN) && parseInt(sFN) > -1 ? sFN : (sFN != "" && sFN != "-1" ? sFN : "-")) : (sFN == "-1" ? (sFN != "" ?  "-" : sFN) : sFN)) +'</td>';
                            }
                    }
                        sH += '<td><a id="stundethistoryhide_'+k1.replace("___", "")+'" onmouseover="javascript:CommonFunctions.AddToolTip(this.id,\'Hide\');" onmouseup="javascript:CommonFunctions.DeleteToolTip(this.id);" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small" onclick="javascript:removeRow('+k1.replace("___", "")+', '+ Tl +', \''+ sTN +'\');"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>'; //This is not correct. Why you need length of the object for each iteration of the object
                    sH += '</tr>';
                    if(lSO.length > 0) {
                        sH += '<tr class="assess-info-row" style='+(jQuery.inArray(("sp_"+k1.replace("___", "")), oSH.lstTIds) > -1 ? "" : "display:none;")+' id="std_'+k1.replace("___", "")+'">';
                        sH += '<td colspan="9">';//You cant't hardcode colspan here. This should come dynamically based on score topic's
                        sH += '<table class="table table-condensed table-borderless" id="tbl_'+k1.replace("___", "")+'" style="width:800px; table-layout:fixed;">';
                        sH += '<tbody>';
                        sH += '<tr>';
                        for(var ss=1; ss<=lSO.length; ss++){
                        var sST = lSO[ss-1].split("|~|");
                        sH += (sT == "CELDT" ? '<td class="text-left">' +sST[0] + '<div>' + parseInt(sST[1]) + '</div></td>' : '<td><div class="text-left">' +sST[0] + '</div><div class="col-perc-bar-sh"><div class="progressBar" id="max'+(parseInt(sST[1]) > 100 ? 100 : sST[1])+'" style="width:120px; margin:0 auto text-align:left;"><div style="width: '+(parseInt(sST[1]) > 100 ? 100 : sST[1])+'%;"></div></div><div class="percent">' + (parseFloat(sST[1]) > 100 ? 100 : parseFloat(sST[1]).toFixed(oSH.decimalCount)) + '%</div></div></td>'); 
                            if(ss % 5 == 0) sH += '</tr><tr>';
                        }
                        sH += '</tr>';
                        sH += '</tbody>';
                        sH += '</table>';
                        sH += '</td></tr>';
                    }
                }
            });
            sH += '</tbody></table>';
            sH += '</li></ul></li>';
        });
        } else {$("#divNoData").html("No Assessments data."); $("#divNoData").css('display', ''); $("#aExpand").hide();}
        sH += '</ul>';
        $("#divTabs").html(sH);
        $("#divClassSchedule").hide();
        $("#divTabs").show();
        $("#divReportTab").show();
        $("i.icon-minus-sign").addClass("text-orange");
        for(var i = 0; i < oSH.lstTIds.length; i++){
            var y = oSH.lstTIds[i].split("_");
            $("#ulYear_" + y[1] + "_" +y[2]).slideToggle();
            $("#icon_" + oSH.lstTIds[i]).removeClass('icon-minus-sign text-orange').addClass('icon-plus-sign');
        }
        var sTab = (oSH.mpTabStatus[sT] ? oSH.mpTabStatus[sT] : "");//: We are remembering the Expand all and Collapse all while nevagating the tabs in Student History popup.
        if(sTab == "Expand All"){
            oSH.lstTIds.push(sTab + "_All");
            $("#aExpand").text("Expand All");
            expandCollapseAll();
        }else if(sTab == "Collapse All"){
            oSH.lstTIds.splice($.inArray(sTab + "_All", oSH.lstTIds));
            $("#aExpand").text("Collapse All");
            expandCollapseAll();
        }
    }
}
```

This above Method i am writing to show student history with four tabs and in this i have called toggleYearandAssessment(this, 2) this will go to  expandCollapseAll(o,i) method and toggleYearandAssessment(this, 1) this will go to toggleYearandAssessment(this, 1), in this method i want to remember expand all and some of them collapse.

```
    /**
 * Function to toggle Year and Assessment Names to get Standards.
 * @param o contains tr id.
 * @since v1.0
 */
function toggleYearandAssessment(o, i){
    if(i == 2){
        $(o).parents("tr").next().slideToggle();
        $(o).children().toggleClass('icon-minus-sign text-orange icon-plus-sign');
    if($(o).children().hasClass("icon-minus-sign")) {
                if(jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds) == -1) {oSH.lstTIds.push(o.id);}
                console.log("oSH.lstTIds checking in toggleyrAss if ------- " +oSH.lstTIds);
    } else {
        if($(o).children().hasClass("icon-plus-sign")) {
            if(oSH.lstTIds.length > 0 && jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds) > -1){oSH.lstTIds.splice($.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds),1);}
             console.log("oSH.lstTIds checking in toggleyrAss if +++ " +oSH.lstTIds);
        }
    }
    } else {
        console.log("else for +");
        if($(o).children().hasClass("icon-plus-sign")) {
              console.log("oSH.lstTIds checking in toggleyrAss if +++ " +oSH.lstTIds);
            if(oSH.lstTIds.length > 0 && jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds) > -1){oSH.lstTIds.splice($.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds),1);}
        } else {
              console.log("oSH.lstTIds checking in toggleyrAss if +++ " +oSH.lstTIds);
            if(jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds) == -1) {oSH.lstTIds.push(o.id);}
        }
        var lUL = o.id.split("_");
        $("#ulYear_" + lUL[1] + "_" +lUL[2]).slideToggle();
        $(o).children().toggleClass('icon-minus-sign text-orange icon-plus-sign');
    }
    if(!$("i[name=iYearPlusMinus]").hasClass("icon-minus-sign")) $("#aExpand").text("Expand All");
}
/**
 * Method to expand/Collapse all years and standards.
 */
function expandCollapseAll(o,i){
    var tab = '';
    $('#ulTabs .active').each(function () {
        tab = $(this).text();
    });
    //oSH.lstTIds = new Array();
    if($("#aExpand").text() == "Expand All"){
        oSH.mpTabStatus[tab] = "Expand All";//oSH.mpTabStatus[tab] it contains current tab values
        if(jQuery.inArray(tab + "_All", oSH.lstTIds) == -1)oSH.lstTIds.push(tab + "_All");
        //  if(jQuery.inArray(sp_, oSH.lstTIds) > -1 ? ("icon-minus-sign") : "icon-plus-sign")+' name="iPlusMinus"></i>';
        $("i[name=iPlusMinus]").removeClass('icon-plus-sign').addClass("icon-minus-sign text-orange");
        $("i[name=iYearPlusMinus]").removeClass('icon-plus-sign').addClass("icon-minus-sign text-orange");
        $("ul[name=ulYear]").show();
        $(".assess-info-row").show();
        for(var i=0; i<oSH.lstRemove.length; i++){
            $("#std_"+oSH.lstRemove[i]).hide();
        }
        $("#aExpand").text("Collapse All");
    } else  {
        ($("#aExpand").text() == "Collapse All")
        oSH.mpTabStatus[tab] = "Collapse All";//oSH.mpTabStatus[tab] it contains current tab values
        if(oSH.lstTIds.length > 0 && jQuery.inArray(tab + "_All", oSH.lstTIds) > -1){oSH.lstTIds.splice($.inArray(tab + "_All", oSH.lstTIds),1);}
        $("i[name=iPlusMinus]").removeClass("icon-minus-sign text-orange").addClass('icon-plus-sign');
        $(".assess-info-row").hide();
        $("ul[name=ulYear]").hide();
        $("#aExpand").text("Expand All");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone can read the code what you have tried now.. better create a fiddle and demonstrate...

Comment: As i m getting value from service i cant run in fiddle. Just i want how to remember some of them as collapsed in Exapnd All, where as we can remember collapse All and Expand All

Answer (score 0):

Declare one array in default method :oSH.lstRemTIds = new Array();
than push the selected items to this array in function toggleYearandAssessment(o, i) as:

```
    function toggleYearandAssessment(o, i){
    if(i == 2){
        $(o).parents("tr").next().slideToggle();
        $(o).children().toggleClass('icon-minus-sign text-orange icon-plus-sign');
        if($(o).children().hasClass("icon-minus-sign")) {
            if(jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds) == -1) {oSH.lstTIds.push(o.id);}
        } else {
            if(oSH.lstTIds.length > 0 && jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds) > -1){oSH.lstTIds.splice($.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds),1);}
        }
        if(jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstRemTIds) == -1) {oSH.lstRemTIds.push(o.id);}
    } else {
        if($(o).children().hasClass("icon-plus-sign")) {
            if(oSH.lstTIds.length > 0 && jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds) > -1){oSH.lstTIds.splice($.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds),1);}
        } else {
            if(jQuery.inArray(o.id, oSH.lstTIds) == -1) {oSH.lstTIds.push(o.id);}
        }
        var lUL = o.id.split("_");
        $("#ulYear_" + lUL[1] + "_" +lUL[2]).slideToggle();
        $(o).children().toggleClass('icon-minus-sign text-orange icon-plus-sign');
    }
    if(!$("i[name=iYearPlusMinus]").hasClass("icon-minus-sign")) $("#aExpand").text("Expand All");
}
```

And add if(expandCollapseAll.arguments[0] && expandCollapseAll.arguments[0] == 1) condition in function expandCollapseAll() method as:

```
   function expandCollapseAll(){
    var tab = '';
    $('#ulTabs .active').each(function () {
        tab = $(this).text();
    });
    //oSH.lstTIds = new Array();
    if($("#aExpand").text() == "Expand All"){
        oSH.mpTabStatus[tab] = "Expand All";//oSH.mpTabStatus[tab] it contains current tab values
        if(jQuery.inArray(tab + "_All", oSH.lstTIds) == -1)oSH.lstTIds.push(tab + "_All");
        $("i[name=iPlusMinus]").removeClass('icon-plus-sign').addClass("icon-minus-sign text-orange");
        $("i[name=iYearPlusMinus]").removeClass('icon-plus-sign').addClass("icon-minus-sign text-orange");
        $("ul[name=ulYear]").show();
        $(".assess-info-row").show();
        for(var i=0; i<oSH.lstRemove.length; i++){
            $("#std_"+oSH.lstRemove[i]).hide();
        }
        $("#aExpand").text("Collapse All");
    } else {
        oSH.mpTabStatus[tab] = "Collapse All";//oSH.mpTabStatus[tab] it contains current tab values
        if(oSH.lstTIds.length > 0 && jQuery.inArray(tab + "_All", oSH.lstTIds) > -1){oSH.lstTIds.splice($.inArray(tab + "_All", oSH.lstTIds),1);}
        $("i[name=iPlusMinus]").removeClass("icon-minus-sign text-orange").addClass('icon-plus-sign');
        $(".assess-info-row, #ulYear").hide();
        $("#aExpand").text("Expand All");
    }
    if(expandCollapseAll.arguments[0] && expandCollapseAll.arguments[0] == 1){
        $.each(oSH.lstRemTIds, function(k1, v1){
            if($("#aExpand").text() == "Collapse All"){
                $("#"+v1).parents("tr").next().slideToggle();
                $("#"+v1 + " > i ").removeClass("icon-minus-sign text-orange").addClass('icon-plus-sign');
            }else{
                $("#"+v1).parents("tr").next().slideToggle();
                $("#"+v1 + " > i ").removeClass('icon-plus-sign').addClass("icon-minus-sign text-orange");
            }
        });
    } else oSH.lstRemTIds = new Array();
}
```